# Update table using with temp CTE

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, common-table-expression, delta-lake

```
%sql
with temp1 as 
(
  select req_id from table1 order by timestamp desc limit 8000000
)
    
update table1  set label = '1'  where req_id in temp1 and req_query like '%\<\/script\>%' 

update table1  set label = '1'  where req_id in temp1 and req_query like '%aaaaa%' 
update table1  set label = '1'  where req_id in temp1 and req_query like '%bbbb%'
```

getting error:

> com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
> mismatched input 'in' expecting {, ';'}(line 6, pos 93)

can someone advise? what will be less costly to ask the database the same question?

```
select req_id from table1 order by timestamp desc limit 8000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed: `where req_id in temp1`. `temp1` is not a list, but the result of a query and should be used like another table.
You might rather write something like this:

```sql
update table1
   set label = '1'
 where req_id in (select req_id from table1 order by timestamp desc limit 8000000)
   and req_query like '%\<\/script\>%'
```

Comment: if i have multiple time this condition:
update table1
   set label = '1'
 where req_id in (select req_id from table1 order by timestamp desc limit 8000000)
   and req_query like '%\<\/script\>%' 
update table1
   set label = '1'
 where req_id in (select req_id from table1 order by timestamp desc limit 8000000)
   and req_query like '%or 1=1%'
it will query every time the database...

Comment: sorry I do not understand what you mean, but you should update your first post to add this precision, it will be easier to understand with the proper formatting

Comment: edit my question.

Comment: I see... anyway, a cte will not be of any use in your case. I would rather consider a loop and build a dynamic query (the string in your `like` statement would be a parameter) based on the query I propose you above

Answer (score 0):

You can use update with join instead of IN clause.
Delta does not support updating tables using inner join but you can use [MERGE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html) I think. Something like this:

```sql
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT req_id FROM table1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 8000000
)

MERGE INTO table1 a 
USING temp1 b
ON (a.req_id = b.req_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET a.label = CASE WHEN a.req_query LIKE '%\<\/script\>%' THEN '1'
                          WHEN a.req_query LIKE '%aaaaa%'        THEN '2'
                          WHEN a.req_query LIKE '%bbbb%'         THEN '3'
                          ELSE a.label 
                     END
```